# Parametric degradation reliability solution needed

Tags: probability-distributions, logarithms, reliability

[image]Working on a reliability project and ran across this problem of parametric degradation over time relative to a failure threshold.

Need to calculate the distribution of failure times $t_{f,i}$ for a set of devices  $i=1...N $ where failure is defined parametrically as $|S_{i}(t)|\ge S_{f}$ and failure times per device as $|S_{i}(t_{f,i})|=S_f$ where $S_{i}(t) = A_{i} \ln (1+bt)$ and $\{S_{i}(t_1)\}$ , where at a time $t=t_1<t_{f,i}$ for all $i$, is Gaussian distributed with mean $\mu $ and standard deviation $\sigma $, i.e. $N(\mu,\sigma).$

In contrast, it is relatively easy to show that if instead the degradation path were a simple power law, $S_{t}(t)=At^{n}$ that the resultant failure time distribution is lognormal with log-mean $\ln t_{1} + \frac{1}{n}\ln(\frac{S_{f}}{\mu})$ and log-standard deviation $\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+\frac{\sigma}{\mu})$

Comment: Your MathJax code had a lot of purposeless complications.

Comment: I cleaned them up and then you reinstated them -- you undid all of my edits.

Comment: please suggest edits

Comment: How about the edits that I already did that you undid?

Comment: I could not see them

Comment: Click on the edit history.

Comment: not available on platform I'm using ... Android phone app

Comment: I've done them again. \left and \right are need in things like $\left( 1 + \dfrac 1 b\right),$ where otherwise you'd get $(1 + \dfrac 1 b),$ but in things like $f(x),$ writing $f\left( x \right)$ just complicates things. And you don't need to enclose whatever follows $\ln$ in curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

The failure theshold of a normal distribution is related to the divergence of the generating function. The generating function is an expression which arrives at the maximal changes between data points as the sample space expands.

In this case the data is the parametic representation of some function

$ S(t_{n}) = Aln(1+bt_{n}) $

The $ k^{th} $ moment is the $ k^{th} $ derivative of the generating function for the sample space, usually in the form of an exponential expansion of the function being used. (This way it is infinitely continuous and has uniform and proportional continuity throughout)

$$ e^{S(t_{n})} = \Sigma_{n=1}^{k}\frac{(S(t_{n}))^{n}}{n!}  $$

Noting that $ S(t_{n})^{2} = S_{n}^{2} = A^{2}ln(1+bt)^{2} = 2A^{2}ln(1+bt) $

and that $ ln(1 + x) = x $ for $ x < N $ where $ N $ is a large number.

we can say that $ (S(t_{n}))^{n} = S_{n}^{n} = nbtA^{n} $

Thus $ e^{S(t_{n})} = \Sigma_{n = 1}^{k} \frac{nbtA^{n}}{n!} $

To get the generating function for the $ k^{th} $ values of the sample space, we take the $k^{th} $ derivative of this exponential expansion.

$$ \frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}} \Sigma_{n = 1}^{k} \frac{nbtA^{n}}{n!} = S_{k}^{k}$$

Then $ \mu_{k} = \Sigma_{n = 1}^{N}\frac{S_{k_{n}}}{n} $

The $ k^{th} $ sigma, goes as followed. $ k = 1 $ is the variance, $ k = 2 $ is the standard deviation, and $ k = 3 $ is:

$ \sigma^{3} = \sqrt[3]{\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(t_{n} - t\right)^{3}}{n}} $

The normal distribution

$$ N(\mu_{k},\sigma_{k}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu_{k})^{k}}{2\sigma^{k}}} $$

Will then represent the failure threshold when $ k $ exceeds the inequalities for the initial distribution:

$$ \mu_{k} - k\sigma < S_{1} $$
$$ \mu_{k} + k\sigma > S_{1} $$

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'll need to re-read it a few times. I think the concepts you presented are useful, and it'll take me a bit to see how it helps me map $S(t_{1}) = N (\mu, \sigma) $ into the CDF for $t(S_{f})$ via the 'kernel' $S=\ln (1+bt) $

Comment: I've clarified the question considerably, including a schematic of the problem statement ...

Comment: For the case $ bt > N $ see here for the kth moment of a lognormal distribution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795652/how-to-find-nth-moment